# How do I get the internal id of a Node Timeout using the symbol without hardcoding a lookup index?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

When you create a timer in Node, you get the following object back:

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 500,
  _idlePrev: [TimersList],
  _idleNext: [TimersList],
  _idleStart: 34,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: null,
  _destroyed: false,
  [Symbol(unrefed)]: false,
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 5,
  [Symbol(triggerId)]: 1 }
```

The actual numeric id of this timeout object is contained under the `[Symbol(asyncId)]` field. My problem is, how can I get a reference to this symbol in a non-hackish way? The only way I currently know of that will give me this object is `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`, but using a hardcoded index seems fragile as f:

```
$ node -p 't=setTimeout(()=>{}, 500); triggerSym=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t)[2];t[asyncId]'
67
```

Is there a less fragile way I can get a reference to this symbol to use for lookup?

Comment: Do you want the ID, or do you want the symbol? Your title seems to be asking a different question from the body of the question. As long as you're in a recent version of node, ToPrimitive will give you the ID directly, e.g. `const timerId = +timer;`

Comment: Good question. The title implies I want both and that is also what I want. My original issue was "how do I get hold of the timer id", but then I got curious as to how I could get a reference to the symbol. Hence the question. Good to know about ToPrimitive bit, but it's actually not correct (I just tried). You get the field located using `Symbol(asyncId)`, not the field located using `Symbol(triggerId)`. So given the example above, you would get `5`, not `1`.

Comment: Or "not correct" might not be correct. It's not what I originally wanted at least :-) The `asyncId` might be the id, but I thought I wanted the other field. You are probably right that asyncId is the id. I found a way, btw, through string matching: `node -p 't=setTimeout(()=>{}, 500); triggerSym=Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(t).find(s=>s.description=="triggerId"); t[triggerSym]'`

Comment: `node -p 'i=1500; while(i--) t=setTimeout(()=>{}, 500); t'` shows that the asyncId does increase to 1501, whereas the triggerId stays put at 1.

Feel free to post your comment as an answer, as that is correct wrt the timer id, and I will add a section on how to get the symbol through the string matching.

Comment: Yeah not sure, sometimes it just happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` to list the symbols of the timer object and then iterate to find the one you want. In my opinion that is pretty ugly and basically the same as relying on an implementation detail or using a `_foo` private-ish property on an object.

Currently the main case I know of for public symbol usage in Node is with [promisifyable functions](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifycustom), where users can use

```
const promisifySymbol = Symbol.for('nodejs.util.promisify.custom');
```

The [Node timer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html) have no mention of such symbols, so I would recommend not using these symbols.

If you do need the ID itself to handle serialization of the timer's info or something, the [`timer [Symbol.toPrimitive]()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timeoutsymboltoprimitive) implementation returns the ID directly, or indirectly, e.g.

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {}, 0);

console.log(timer[Symbol.toPrimitive]()); // explicit call
console.log(+timer); // implicit call
```

Comment: "*If you do need the ID*" then you absolutely should use the toPrimitive coercion, since without that it won't be possible to use the id in `clearTimeout`. See [`knownTimersById` in the implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c4096a35d651399f79948395c233747dcacc83aa/lib/timers.js#L256-L267).

Comment: @Bergi Ah great point.

Comment: @Bergi Not sure I get you ... You don't need to pull the primitive version of a timer to use it in a clearTimeout. You can just supply the entire timer object.  `node -e 't=setTimeout(function f(){ console.log("hei"); }, 1000); clearTimeout(t)'`. Did I misunderstand you by losing some context?

Comment: @oligofren I was assuming you wanted to use the timer id as a reference to the timer that you can serialise and deserialise, e.g. a roundtrip through a JSON representation. What else would you need the id for? Yes, in general you should just use the entire timer object.

Comment: I am on the Sinon team, maintaining the `fake-timers` package, so I assume I needed it for re-creating the behavior of the Node internals. The details escape me :)